# Finding $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(- \frac{1}{n}, \frac{n}{2n+1}\right)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Upon defining $A_n = \left(- \frac{1}{n}, \frac{n}{2n+1}\right)$, I am trying to find and prove $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$. Since $- \frac{1}{n}, \frac{n}{2n+1}$ converge to $0$ as sequences, I am fairly sure that the answer is $0$ (though I don't have any other intuition other than thinking of them sequences). Here is my attempt at proving it.

> I claim that $\bigcap\limits_{n-1}^{\infty} A_n = \{0\}$. For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $- \frac{1}{n} < 0 < \frac{n}{2n+1}$, so $0 \in A_n$ for all $n$, hence $0 \in \bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$. Furthermore, given $x < 0$, we can find a sufficiently large $N$ such that $- \frac{1}{N} > x$. so $x \not \in A_n$ and hence $x \not \in \bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$. Furthermore, given $x > 0$, we can find an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ for which $N > x$. Then, since $N \geq 1$, $2N + 1 \geq 1$, so $x(2N + 1) \geq x > N$, so $x > \frac{N}{2N+1}$, so $x \not \in A_N$, and hence $x \not \in \bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$. Therefore, if $x \neq 0$, $x \not \in \bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}$, so $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n = \{0\}$.

How does this look? Is there a better way to either intuitively come up with this or to prove this? I'm not particularly comfortable with how I proved that $x > 0$ was not in the intersection.

Comment: Are you sure that $\{\frac{n}{2n+1}\}$ converges to zero?

Comment: Note that in your attempt you first wanted to have $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $N > x$ but later you use $x > N$ in order to get the result you tried to prove.

Answer (score 4):

Your general technique is roughly okay, but the answer should be $[0, \tfrac{1}{3})$.  This is because the upper bound on the intervals is *increasing* so it is minimised when $n=1$.  Try to re-do your proof to establish this result.  (Also, be careful with your consistency of notation; if $-\tfrac{1}{N} > x$ then you have $x \notin A_N$, not $x \notin A_n$.)

Comment: The fact that the upper bound of the intervals is increasing is not sufficient for the upper bound of the intersection to be  achieved when $n=1$. It may also depend on the behavior of the lower bounds of the intervals.

Comment: In general yes, but the lower bounds are all negative in this example (and therefore bounded above by zero).

Comment: I have no intuition for why the intersection comes out to $\frac{1}{2}$, though I realize that my argument for why it was $\{0\}$ was faulty. If I consider the sequence $\frac{n}{2n + 1}$, I see that it converges to $\frac{1}{2}$ in the limit of large $n$, but is never actually equal to $\frac{1}{2}$. Would the intersection be $[0, \frac{1}{2})$? I believe the argument I made for why anything less than $0$ won't work ends up being OK, I believe, with the addition you made. So I would only need to argue that $(0, \frac{1}{2})$ is contained and rule out $x > \frac{1}{2}$. Is that right?

Comment: Let's just go through the values.  For $n=1,2,3,4,...$ we get $\tfrac{n}{2n+1} = \tfrac{1}{3}, \tfrac{2}{5}, \tfrac{3}{7}, \tfrac{4}{9}, ...$.  Yes, this converges to $\tfrac{1}{2}$, but which of these values is the smallest (end therefore gives the upper bound of the intersection)?